# How to perform a simple calculation in a CSV and append the results to the file

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, append

I have a csv which contains 38 colums of data, all I want to find our how to do is, divide column 11 by column by column 38 and append this data tot he end of each row. Missing out the title row of the csv (row 1.)

If I am able to get a snippet of code that can do this, I will be able to manipulate the same code to perform lots of similar functions.

My attempt involved editing some code that was designed for something else.
See below:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class_col = 11
data_col = 38

# Read in the data
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    # if you have a header on the file
    # header = f.readline().strip().split(',')
    data = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]

# Append the relevant sum to the end of each row
for row in xrange(len(data)):
    data[row].append(int(class_col)/int(data_col))

# Write the results to a new csv file
with open('testMODIFIED2.csv', 'w') as nf:
    nf.write('\n'.join(','.join(row) for row in data))
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks SMNALLY

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes I have I have tried to manipulate some old code. Ill include in the question.

Comment: I recommend using `csv.dictreader` to turn your csv into a dictionary and then just accessing the values for column 11 and column 38 by their fieldnames.
(see http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html and various examples at SO)

Comment: Hi this dictreader method sounds interesting, any chance of providing an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as old_csv:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(old_csv)
    with open('testMODIFIED2.csv', 'wb') as new_csv:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_csv)
        for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
            if i != 0:
                row.append(float(row[10]) / float(row[37]))
                csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Upon trying to test this I got this traceback: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test rewrite.py", line 10, in <module>
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
IOError: File not open for writing`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I recieved the same traceback.

Comment: @AEA - sorry, I forgot to specify the mode in the open statements.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the changes, I currently get the traceback, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File  `line 9, in <module>
    row.append(float(row[10]) / float(row[37]))
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero` Any thoughts how to overcome this ?

Comment: There are probably some zeroes in row 38 of the csv file.  One solution would be to wrap the division line with a try catch block and  insert a null value in the new column when row 38 is 0.  It all depends on how you want to handle that particular scenario.

Comment: My fault. Was column 48 not 38 :)

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv') #assumes header row exists
df['FRACTION'] = 1.0*df['CLASS']/df['DATA'] #by default new columns are appended to the end
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```